# return after call doFilter() of GenericFilterBean on Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, filter, servlet-filters

I am using GenericFilterBean as filter on my Spring boot project.

In some case, I want to pass next filter  on my filter logic.

My filter looks like below;

```
public class MyFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

        @Override
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

            HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;

            if (anyCondition){
                chain.doFilter();
                return;         
            }

            if (anyCondition){
                chain.doFilter();
                return;         
            }

            if (anyCondition){
                chain.doFilter();
                return;         
            }

            chain.doFilter();

        }

    }
```

it calls other chain.doFilter() if I don’t return, that’s way I return.

İt will caused any problem to return after call chain.doFilter() ?

Is it right way to handle this situations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will always call `chain.doFilter` (not doChain)

for example

```java
    public class MyFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

        @Override
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

            HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;

            //this gets executed before other filters
            some code here

            //now we execute other filters
            chain.doFilter(request, response); 

            //this code gets executed after the 'next' filters are done
            some code here

        }

    }
```

But your code always executes the *next* filter and then is complete.
Your code is fine, but you can do it with an `if then else` statement instead

```java
    public class MyFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

        @Override
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

            HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;

            if (condition1){
                //do something for condition1
            } else if (condition2) {
                //do something for condition2
            }  else if (condition3) {
                //do something for condition3
            }
            chain.doChain();

        }

    }
```

Comment: no problem calling return, but it is a style many people don't like. it will work just fine tho and it means this: 1. call the next filter(s) 2. exit the current method